# Install python package without internet connection

Tags: python, pip

I need to install python packages with pip on a machine without internet access. To do that, I tried to download these packages from the following link : [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
I thought the whl files are complete packages but when I try to install with pip I get the following error

pip install .\pyproj-3.2.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl

```
        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewC
    onnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000F76ABA6EC0>: Failed to establish a new
     connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from pyproj) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi
```

The packages I need to install are:

- Numpy
- GDAL
- PYPROJ
- FIONA
- SHAPELY
- GEOPANDAS

I also tried with pip download on my local machine with internet connection but when I try to use the generated whl I get the same issue

How should I proceed to install theses packages?

Comment: How, exactly, did you do this?  Please show us the commands.

Comment: This looks like there were some dependecies. Packages often are built on top of others (e.g. `pandas` needs `numpy` to function). But without knowing either your packages now command/s, we can only make assumptions.

Comment: Yes that was also my assumption that it needs other dependencies. I have edited my post with more details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works.

1. On a machine with internet I installed all the required packages in a virtual environment.
2. I created a requirement.txt with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
3. I used `pip download -r requirement.txt` to download the packages
4. I copied it onto the other machine.
5. I created a new `requirements.txt` with the filenames (`ls > requirements.txt`).
6. I installed the packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

like this

`pip install --no-index --find-links=<lolcal-folder> <package-name>`

e.g.

`pip install --no-index --find-link=/tmp/python-wheels exchangelib`

[More info here](https://thilinamad.medium.com/install-python-packages-via-pip-without-an-internet-connection-b3dee83b4c2d)